# Tensorflow datasets for translation - how to use the WMT14 manual download?

Tags: python, tensorflow, translation, tensorflow-datasets

I am following the guide here: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/wmt14_translate , but I am running into problems trying to download the dataset, basically it takes forever to download. Regarding the "manual download" mentioned in the TF guide, does it mean I have to manually download it from the links, and place them in my local tensorflow_datasets folder? Based on the code output, it looks like it's trying to download the data anyway.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

datasets, metadata = tfds.load('wmt14_translate/de-en', with_info=True,
                               as_supervised=True)
print(metadata)
train_examples, val_examples, test_examples = datasets['train'], datasets['validation'], datasets['test']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it does take a very long time to download as even the dataset is huge(around 1.5 Gb). And no, you don't need to download the data manually, just wait till the code runs and u are good to go.

P.S. In my case I had to run the

> dataset = tfds.load('wmt14_translate/de-en',
> split='test',shuffle_files=True)

cell again to get all the examples in the `dataset`(the 2nd run doesn't take any time), else after just the first run, I was getting only a one parallel sentence pair, idk why.